# Is product/coproduct in category with only one object possible?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let's say we have category with one object $N$ and infinite number of arrows, which are named as natural numbers, with the same law of composition, where $id$ arrow 0.
I try to understand 1) if categorical product/coproduct could be defined in such category and 2) if it could have properties of usual binary operations on natural numbers?

Comment: This category is just the monoid $(\mathbb{N},+)$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thats' what I mean. I forgot the word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category you describe lacks any interesting products and coproducts. But there is a category with only one object that has very interesting products and coproducts. Namely, let $A$ be a [$III_1$ factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Type_III_factors), and consider the category with only one object and endomorphisms of that object indexed by elements of $A$ (and composition given by multiplication). It is not obvious, but this category has both products and coproducts.

Comment: So, just to check I understand: a monoid $A$ has n-fold products (when thought of as a category with one object) if there are elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ such that for any $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in A$, there exists $d\in A$ such that $a_i d = b_i$ for $i=1, \ldots n$. Seems like a strange property! Do monoids with this property have a name?

Comment: Oh, I think I see where such things might come from... the monoid of self-maps of a countable set should have this property, as it is equivalent to the category of countable sets. This category has at least countable products and coproducts.

Comment: I mean countably infinite, of course.

Answer (score 2):

A more abstract answer. In some category, let $X$ be an object with isomorphisms $X\cong X\times X$, $X\cong X\sqcup X$ (for example, in the category of sets an empty set, a one-element set or any infinite set have this property). Then the full subcategory with single object $X$ will have all nonempty finite products and coproducts. That simply because this subcategory is equivalent to the full subcategory on finite products and coproducts of $X$.

PS Just noticed that Sam Gunningham has this in a comment to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a single object, products are powers; the only power that exists is when the index set is a singleton. Similarly, the coproduct only exists if the index set is a singleton

A product of a family $\{X_i\}$ is supposed to be an object $X$ together with morphism $f_i\colon X\to X_i$ such that for every object $C$ and ever family $\{g_i\colon C\to X_i\}$, there exists a unique $G\colon C\to X$ such that $f_i\circ G = g_i$. In your setting, this would amount to an $I$-tuple $(n_i\colon N\to N)$ of numbers such that given any $I$-tuple $(k_i)$, there exists a unique natural number $K$ such that $n_i+K = k_i$ for all $i$. You can only guarantee this if $I$ is a singleton, and $n_i = 0$.

The coproduct would likewise be an $I$-tuple $(n_i\colon N\to N)$ with the property that given any $I$-tuple $(k_i)$ of natural numbers, there is a number $K$ such that $n_i + K = k_i$ for all $i$. So again this only exists for a singleton with $n_i=0$.

Comment: In the last part of the answer, about coproducts, shouldn't the equation $k_i+k=n_i$ rather be $n_i+K=k_i$? The only difference between products and coproducts should be the order of composition, which makes no difference in the present case where composition is commutative. Besides, in any category whatsoever, any family indexed by a singleton has a coproduct (and a product), namely the unique member of the family with its identity map.

Comment: Also, in both the product part and the coproduct part, "there is a number $K$" should be "there is a unique number $K$". The uniqueness (which you had correctly mentioned earlier in connection with $G$) is needed to prevent the empty family from seeming to have a product and a coproduct.  When $I=\varnothing$, there is an appropriate $K$, but it isn't unique; in fact any $K$ will do.

Comment: The notions of "product" and "coproduct" are symmetric under reversing arrows. So is the notion "category with a single object". So it cannot be correct that a category with a single object necessarily has [blah] products and [other blah] coproducts unless [blah] = [other blah].

Comment: The category of nonzero (separable Hilbert) modules for a Type III_1 factor has only one object, but has (finite and infinite, but non-empty) products and coproducts.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thank you for the corrections; you are of course correct.